# If there was no friction would a thin rectangle with mass $m$ with sides $a$ and $b$ spin indefinitely about an axis through its diagonal?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

I would like a geometrical physics answers so I can have an intuitive grasp about the problem. That means no nonphysical things like matrices, coordinates and random basis of vectors.

For example it the initial period of revolution was t , when is it going to stop.

Comment: Do you mean the mass is a rectangle? Is the mass in free space, is one corner on a table?

Comment: Look from energy point of view as the disappative forces don't exist so the energy of the system is a constant quantity and hence if the plate has a fixed moment of inertia then we have that it rotates for infinite time....

Comment: Is there gravity or some other source of torque? If there is gravity, what is the orientation of the thin rectangle?

Comment: Gravity doesn't matter, if you had a square and it's rotating about a physical axis piercing it through it's diagonal it would never stop , but rectangle has a more complicated moment of inertia